# setCustomValidity on .ajaxForm() beforeSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, ajaxform

I'm loading a form into a modal dialog on button click and attaching .ajaxForm() to it on load. ajaxForm() has a beforeSubmit function in which I call two functions to validate username and password fields and setting .setCustomValidity() on them. I imagined it would go something like this; clicking Submit validation is done in beforeSubmit and setCustomValidity is set on invalid fields; then, a message appears on submit attempt.

However, messages appear only after I click Submit the second time. The first time it does nothing.

This is the form.

```
<form method="POST" action="/scripts/register.php" id="register-form">
  <input minlength="6" maxlength="15" type="text" id="user" name="user" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" placeholder="Username" required>
  <input minlength="6" maxlength="15" type="password" id="pass" name="pass" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" placeholder="Password" required>
  <input minlength="6" maxlength="15" type="password" id="confirm_pass" name="confirm_pass" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
  <input type="submit" name="login" class="button" value="Login">
</form>
```

Loading form into a dialog

```
$( "body" ).on("click","#register",function(){
    $(".modal-dialog").load("register-form.php", function(){
        $('#register-form').ajaxForm({ 
            beforeSubmit : function(){
                check_password_validity();
                check_username_validity();
            }
        });
    });
    $( ".dialog-overlay" ).addClass( 'dialog-overlay-open' );
});
```

And the two functions where I setCustomValidity:

```
function check_password_validity(){
var pass = $("#pass").val();
var pass2 = $("#confirm_pass").val();
if(!is_alnum(pass)){
    $("#pass")[0].setCustomValidity("Samo alfanumerički znakovi, bez razmaka i posebnih znakova.");
    return;
}
if(pass!=pass2){
    $("#confirm_pass")[0].setCustomValidity("Lozinke se ne podudaraju!");
    return;
}
}
function check_username_validity(){
var user = $("#user").val();
if(!is_alnum(user)){
    $("#user")[0].setCustomValidity("Samo alfanumerički znakovi, bez razmaka i posebnih znakova.");
    return;
}
$.post( "/scripts/check_username_exists.php", {username: user}, function( data ) {
    if(data=="true"){
        $("#user")[0].setCustomValidity("Korisnik s tim imenom već postoji.");
        return;
    }
});
}
```

This works and all, but the messages appear on second submit attempt, after Submit buttons is clicked the second time. It seems like I'm missing something simple but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Anything changes when you switch places with the load and addClass?

Comment: addCLass is there just to get dialog to show. It's always there it's just hidden. Nothing changes when I switch it with .load()

Comment: Not a solution, but I opted for custom notifcations (notifiy.js) and validating inside the ajax script, echoing back a response that is a script and then eval(response), essentialy executing a script that shows a notification. What I don't like is that HTML5 validation messages are not matching my notifications, but I'm looking to style those anyhow in the future to match my websites notifications.